# How to be notified o a Component or child GameObject has been added to a GameObject

Tags: c#, notifications, unity-game-engine

Is there anyway I can be notified (possibly through some method/event raised) when a `Component` is added to a `GameObject` (and even child GameObject)?

I'd like to be notified(possibly in some editors scripts) when some events occurs in the editor for example:

- A `Component` has been **attached** to a `GameObject` instance
- A `Component` has been **attached** to a `Prefab`
- A `GameObject` has become **child** of another `GameObject` istance

Is this possible?If yes how?

---

EDIT

I found out a delegate for what concern parenting:[EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowChanged](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.OnHierarchyChange.html?from=EditorApplication)

Accordingly to the doc it's called :

> Called whenever the scene hierarchy has changed.
>
> This is transform.parent changed, gameObject.name, creating a new game
>   object, etc.

I still don't understand if there's a convinient way to understood which Object in the hierarchy has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a component to an object in your (editor-only) level-editing scene:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelEditorHelper : MonoBehaviour
{
    LevelEditorHelper()
    {
        EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowChanged -= MyHierarchyChangedCallback;
        EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowChanged += MyHierarchyChangedCallback;
    }

    private static void MyHierarchyChangedCallback()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hierarchy has changed");
    }
}
#endif
```

Then within the callback you can access the current selected object (the added object will be the active selection):

```
GameObject activeObj = Selection.activeGameObject;
if(activeObj != null) {
    ...
```

And now you can check its parent to see if it matches whatever other object, and perform other checks to ensure this is actually the event you're interested in (remember it will be called for various other hierarchy changes too), then you can call another function to do whatever action you want.

**Note:** This won't work as-is for in-game scenes, if you edit your in-game scenes directly with your level-editor scripts then you'll need to use more careful placement of `#if UNITY_EDITOR` and consider how to remove the unnecessary component (perhaps in `Start` or at build-time if possible), or just leave it there doing nothing if you're happy with that. In my case my level editor is an editor-only scene, and it saves out a specific sub-set of the editor scene as a scene for use in-game.

Answer (score -1):

There is no "built-in" way of doing this conveniently.  However, you could simulate it in a couple of ways.

- Utilize the `Awake()` function in your Component to call it's parent `gameObject` (`SendMessage` works very cleanly for this) [note: this only works if you're adding a NEW component instance]

OR

- Create a variable to track it's parent. In the `Update()` method, check current parent to trigger the SendMessage to the new parent.

  Here's just 2 examples of what *could* work for situation--there's plenty more.  At the end of the day, nothing built is (as of yet), but certainly do-able from a work-around standpoint.